# Group 'calc()' CSS property; using margin shorthand?

Tags: html, css, calc

Is it possible to shorten the below, because notice how the value [6.25% - 5px] is the same, and really it should be only defined once.

```
margin-top:calc(6.25% - 5px);margin-bottom:calc(6.25% - 5px)
```

To something more like:

```
margin:calc(6.25% 0 0 - 5px)
```

However, it is the [0 0] part that is causing the error, and my point is when defining the margin - you should always use the shorthand; defining each direction individually.

To put this in context, I am using this for the footer:

[margin-top]

---

contact information

---

[margin-bottom]

Comment: `margin:calc(6.25% - 5px) 0`

Comment: Wouldn't a shorthand of <value> 0 0 evaluate to <value> for the top and *left* margins rather than the top and bottom ones anyway?

Comment: calc is an expression that returns a single value. You can provide a calculation for each of the values of the `margin` shorthand, for instance: `margin:calc(6.25% - 5px) calc(30% - 50px)` to have a top/bottom margin with a calculation and a left/right margin with a calculation. In your case, since left/right is 0, you only need one calculation and the other value is just `0`:  `margin:calc(6.25% - 5px) 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax, if you wanted to set the top/bottom and left/right margins, for the margin shorthand property is:

```
margin: TB_value LR_value
```

You appear to be trying to write it as:

```
margin: TB_LR_value_value
```

Don't put the `0`s in the middle of your TB value. Put them after it as normal. You only need one for the L and R values anyway.

```
margin: calc(6.25% - 5px) 0;
```